# How can I remap the axes of an NDOF device in Blender 3.4?

Tags: interface

While learning how to navigate with a NDOF device, I noticed that it seemed much more intuitive in FreeCAD than in Blender.  I am trying for the "reach in to the screen and grab the object" configuration.  These are my NDOF settings so far:

[image: NDOF settings]

I also found `Navigation`, `Orbit Around Selection` very useful.

In both applications:

- Moving the puck up/down/left/right moves the object up, down, left and right within the viewport
- Pulling the puck up and pushing it down bring the object closer and move it further away respectively
- Tipping (rotating) the puck forwards and backwards controls tilt.  This makes it easy to orbit in this direction by combining this movement with puck up/down

But in FreeCAD, tipping the puck to the left or right pans around the object while turning the puck like a dial rolls the camera.

In Blender, moving the puck like a dial pans around the object.  Tipping left/right does nothing because `Turntable` and that's great.

I'd like to remap the tipping left/right axis to control panning around the object because I think this is what makes it more intuitive to use in FreeCAD.  Combining the "dial" movement of the puck with moving it left/right to pan around the object while keeping it in view is very difficult and doesn't work the same way as tilting around the object.

How can I remap the axes, or is there a better approach to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Regarding "typos": "axes" is plural of "axis".  1 axis, 2 axes.